# Compute $\int_0^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx$

Tags: integration

I haven't integrated in a while... so I'm a bit rusty. I have to integrate $\int_0^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx$. Should I apply some change of variables? If I take $u=x-1/2$, I get something of the form $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+1/4}}du$ (along with another integral, which I can integrate), but I don't know how to deal with this one.

Comment: First of all simplify the function, $\frac{x}{\sqrt {x(1-x)}} = \sqrt{ \frac{x^2}{x(1-x)}}= \sqrt{ \frac{x}{1-x}} $, can you continue from here

Comment: Substituting $u=\sqrt{1-x}$ gives $2\int_0^1\sqrt{1-u^2}\,\mathrm du=\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-u^2}\,\mathrm du$ which is the area of half the unit circle and thus is $\pi/2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $x=\sin^2 \theta$, then
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 \sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\ dx =&\ \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2\theta}{1-\sin^2\theta}} d(\sin^2\theta)\\
=&\ \int^{\pi/2}_0 \tan\theta\ d(\sin^2\theta)\\
=&\ 2\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^2\theta\ d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: I think the integrand has infinite discontinuity hence limit should be calculated at $0+\epsilon $and $1-\delta$ then proper substitution needed. I meant to say it is an improper integral. In your solution, when you started there is an infinite discontinuity at $1$.Hence improper integral isn't it?

Comment: @Math-Learner I agree (though we can keep $0$ fixed and just consider the upper integral limit as going to $1$).

Answer (score 4):

Apply another change of variables to get

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{v^2+1}}dv,$$

and from there, try $v = \sinh x$. Use the following identities:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sinh x = \cosh x\\
\cosh^2x - \sinh x^2 = 1$$

Everything should cancel out nicely; you'll end up with just $\int dx$, which is to say $\sinh^{-1}v$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the property $$ \int_0^a f(x) ~dx = \int_0^a f(a-x) ~dx $$

$$ \mathscr{I} =\int_0^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}~ dx ~= ~\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{(1-x)x}}~ dx $$

Add both the integrals
$$ 2 \mathscr{I} = \int_0^1\frac{x+1-x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}~ dx ~= \int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}~ dx $$

Now, this integral can be easily evaluated by completing the square
$$ \mathscr{I} = \dfrac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac14-(x-\frac12)^2}}~ dx  $$
$$ \mathscr{I} = \dfrac12 ~\sin^{-1} \left( \dfrac{x-\frac12}{\frac12}  \right)_0^1 = \color{red}{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} $$

Comment: This is a very nice approach. It seems to me that the three lines after "Now use" could be skipped, because they don't simplify the integral, they only change the limits.

Comment: @Théophile Yeah, that step was unnecessary. I've removed it now. Thanks.